# Alternet way of menifest&url OTA distribution of ipa

Tags: ios, ipa, ota

Since iOS 8.2, we are facing issues with installation of OTA distribution of enterprise app with menifest&url link. Below is my link that i am using to distribute the app.

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist

We also have developed back-end management console which is tracking users iOS version and app version. So when user successfully installs the app and login, One web-service will update app and iOS version to back-end. We already have distributed app to more than 400 users but some of those have updated their iOS and now they are not able to install the app from link.

When they are clicking the link in iOS safari browser either nothing happens or prompts message "Safari can not install the app this time."

So i just want to replace the way of distribution of app through menifest&url link. Is there any other option available to distribute the app except then menifest&url.

Note: I don't want to use B2B and apple store option. So please do not suggest these ways.

Thanks in advance.